# Select removing dropdown arrow - Cross-browser

Tags: html, css, forms, select

My code works well in all browsers except `IE`. I styled the select but not able to remove the default arrow in `IE`.
Simple code: HTML

```
<form>
<label for="selectitem">Food Favorites</label>
<select id="selectitem">
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <option value="italian">Italian</option>
    <option value="japanese">Japanese</option>
    <option value="mexican">Mexican</option>
    <option value="vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
</select>
</form>
```

CSS code:

```
form {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;          
}

form * {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

select, option {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
    body {
    background: #666;
}

form {
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #DDD;
}

select {
    background: #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url('select.png') no-repeat;
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: solid transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';

}

select:focus {
    background: url('select.png') no-repeat 0 -35px;
}

option {
    background: #666;
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I managed to remove the arrow in Firefox with

```
webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 1px;
text-overflow: '';
```

Image of background for select: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrZqa.png

Comment: behavior: url(PIE.htc) for older IE support

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should *not* style form elements. People are used to them looking like what they look like, and changing that will confuse them.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol You're absolutely right, but some of my employers asking for custom design for forms

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question :)
For Firefox use

```
select {

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

For IE use

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Which -ms-expand is the arrow for Microsoft IE

Comment: Sorry to report: -moz-appearance: none; did nothing to me. FF 32, Mac Os X.

Comment: FYI. You forgot the dash on the webkit. Needs to be `-webkit-appearance: none;`. Also does not work in < IE9

Answer (score -2):

I had success using [jquery-selectBox](https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox)

The style your select box customize the included css file.  Specifically to remove the arrow, modify .select-arrow so that it has display:none

Mine looks as follows:

```
.selectBox-dropdown .selectBox-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 23px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(jquery.selectBox-arrow.gif) 50% center no-repeat;
    border-left: solid 1px #BBB;
    display: none;
}
```